# How to modify multiple keys in a plist

Tags: property-lists

I know I can do something like this:

```
(setq org-format-latex-options (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 1.5)
```

But what If I want to change another property, say `:foreground`, how do I do it? I don't want to repeat the whole thing again, there's gotta be a better way, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would use

```el
(setq org-format-latex-options
      (cdr '(_ :foreground auto         ; default
               :background default
               :scale 1.5               ; 1.0
               :html-foreground "Black"
               :html-background "Transparent"
               :html-scale 1.0
               :matchers ("begin" "$1" "$" "$$" "\\(" "\\["))))
```

or

```el
(setq org-format-latex-options (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 1.5))
(setq org-format-latex-options (plist-put org-format-latex-options :foreground 'auto))
```

because I like simple and obvious solutions. As for you question, you can use

```el
(setq org-format-latex-options
      (plist-put (plist-put org-format-latex-options
                            :scale 1.5)
                 :foreground 'auto))
```

To save more typing, you can define your own `plist-put`, for example,

```el
(defmacro your-plist-put (plist &rest args)
  (let ((list nil))
    (while args
      (push `(setq ,plist (plist-put ,plist ,(pop args) ,(pop args))) list))
    (cons 'progn (nreverse list))))
```

then you can use it in this way,

```el
(your-plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 1.5 :foreground 'auto)

↦

(progn
  (setq org-format-latex-options
        (plist-put org-format-latex-options :scale 1.5))
  (setq org-format-latex-options
        (plist-put org-format-latex-options :foreground 'auto)))
```

Comment: What is the benefit of `(cdr '(_ ...))` over the more common, and IMO clear, `(list ...)` or even just `'(...)`?

Comment: Note also you can use `(macroexp-progn ...)` in place of `(cons 'progn ...)` to forgo the redundant `progn` in case of a single assignment.

Comment: @Basil because Emacs doesn't indent plist correctly, that's a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

See [xuchunyang](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/39474/15748)'s for the more canonical and complete answer; the following is merely a somewhat handy trick specific to property lists, for completeness.

Given:

1. the [underlying structure of lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Cons-Cells.html) in Elisp;
2. a non-empty plist variable; and
3. the [destructive nature of `plist-put`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Plist-Access.html) on non-empty lists,

you can modify a plist variable via `plist-put` directly, without having to reassign its value:

```el
(setq my-plist (list :a 1)) ; my-plist ⇒ (:a 1)
(plist-put my-plist :b 2)   ; my-plist ⇒ (:a 1 :b 2)
(plist-put my-plist :a 3)   ; my-plist ⇒ (:a 3 :b 2)
```

Contrast this with an empty plist variable:

```el
(setq my-plist ())        ; my-plist ⇒ ()
(plist-put my-plist :b 2) ; my-plist ⇒ ()
(plist-put my-plist :a 3) ; my-plist ⇒ ()
```